# TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer - Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got an error TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I´m using spark, I uploaded and open the file 'spark_colab_installer.py', import file from drive, start Spark and create a SparkSession but when I create the sparksession I have the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8WnI.png)

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
exec(open('spark_colab_installer.py').read())

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/datasets_spark.zip /content/
!unzip -q datasets_spark.zip

!pip -q install numpy nltk

import findspark
findspark.init()

import csv
import json
import os
import numpy

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
swords = stopwords.words('english')
tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"\w+")

def vectorize_and_clean_words(data):
    new_line = tokenizer.tokenize(data.lower())
    return [w for w in new_line if w not in swords]

#here I have the error

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()
```

I´m a beginner and I really don´t know what to do to fix it. Any ideas?
my Python version is Python 3.10.12
Thank u!